# How to determine whether MSMQ is in Domain Mode or not

Tags: msmq

How do I check if Microsoft Queueing MSMQ has been installed in Domain Mode or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Important** - installing AD support for MSMQ does NOT mean MSMQ will be automatically AD integrated. For example, if installing under an account without sufficient domain admin privileges. 
From my [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2008/05/14/how-to-tell-if-msmq-is-installed.aspx)

> Note - if you want to verify that MSMQ is actually Active Directory
>   Integrated (not just that Active Directory is installed), you want to
>   check:
>
> •HKLM\Software\Microsoft\MSMQ\Parameters\Workgroup (value should be 0
>   or not present)
>
> •HKLM\Software\Microsoft\MSMQ\Parameters\Setup\CreateMsmqObj (value
>   should exist and be 0; the absence of this key doesn’t necessarily
>   indicate a problem)
>
> The HKLM\Software\Microsoft\MSMQ\Parameters\Workgroup value can be
>   missing if MSMQ Active Directory Integration is installed and MSMQ is
>   successfully operating in domain mode. The presence of this value
>   depends on whether Active Directory Integration was installed before
>   or after the machine was joined to the domain, and whether MSMQ has
>   previously had any failures in contacting the domain controller.
>   Regardless, this key only indicates a problem if its value is 1 and
>   MSMQ is supposed to be Active Directory Integrated

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to view the installed components, e.g. for Windows 2012 R2:

- Manage Server
- Add Roles and Features
- Next until "Select Features"
- OPen "Message Queuing" -> "Message Queueing Services"

If "Directory Service Integration" is enabled, MSMQ is in Directory (Domain) Mode.

Comment: This is not necessarily true. See @johnbreakwell's comment